# How can i protect my html/css/ js work, when giving a link to my employer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, obfuscation

Imagine you sholud give a link for your work, but don't want someone on other side can take your work and proceed with just development.
But it is a document, which browser anyway 'see'. 
Please tell me which tool will allow me to obfuscate completely 
my simple one page html+css+js landing site, so i will be a little bit safer?

It could be command line tool or sublime3 plugin.

Comment: There is no 'obfuscation' techniques because it's client-side. The best you can do is minify

Comment: Why not obfuscate? I'm already used some plugin to obfuscate my js, but I need css+html integrated obfuscating slicer class renamer for html+css+js

Comment: There is no such thing as obfuscating your js.

Comment: My immediate question is, why do you need to do that? ... If there is no trust, show it on your computer until there is.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your code via this tools:

**Css:** https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano or
https://github.com/css/csso

**Javascript:** 
https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

You can also some other javascript or css compressor like:

http://jscompress.com/

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources#overview

Comment: These aren't obfuscators. These are just minifiers

Comment: thank you for your cooperation,https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2 is objusator I believe.

Comment: @DmitryYudin That's a JS minifier, not an obfuscator.

Comment: @DmitryYudin I hope you do realize there is a difference. Obfuscators obscure code with renaming, rereferencing, among other things but minifying only removes redundant code and deletes whitespace, making the loading time shorter for the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can Save your html/css/js work, when giving a link to my employer? by disable to inspect option, disable right click, inspect element or Disable Save page option on your computer.

Use This in your code at header with including jQuery library file.

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==123){
        return false;
    }
    else if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode==73){        
             return false;
    }
});

jQuery(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){        
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

you can also use this code for disable save page option

```
function disableCtrlKeyCombination(e)
    {               
            var forbiddenKeys = new Array("a", "s", "c");
            var key;
            var isCtrl;
            if(window.event)
            {
                    key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
                    if(window.event.ctrlKey)
                            isCtrl = true;
                    else
                            isCtrl = false;
            }
            else
            {
                    key = e.which;     //firefox
                    if(e.ctrlKey)
                            isCtrl = true;
                    else
                            isCtrl = false;
            }

            if(isCtrl)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < forbiddenKeys.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (forbiddenKeys[i].toLowerCase() == String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase())
                            {                                  
                                return false;
                            }
                    }
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Add function on body

```
<body onkeypress="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);" onkeydown="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);" >
```

Comment: This code will not prevent someone (at least in Firefox) from entering `view-source:http://example.com/path/to/file.html` to view the source. It also doesn't prevent someone from simply selecting **`File → Save`**. Firebug is also not disabled. Essentially, it's nearly impossible to prevent someone from viewing the source of your work once it's published online.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript closures are the best way to convert a code into such a way that is very hard to trace.
you may follow google closure compiler to convert you code.

if will minify your code and made changes in logic's.

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for me. Minify package for sublime do all i need.

[check also this](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112530/)

[JS Obf](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/#demo)